# c# how to create a teleprompter like application in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, marquee

I'm developing a C# WinForms application. I can't find a solution to this probably because I'm new.

I need to create a teleprompter like text that scrolls from the bottom and goes up in a loop.
is there any simple solution or a code snippet?

An example would be nice so that I can understand how it is being done.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is you could use the timer control,  handle it Tick event

```
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

Set  myTimer.Interval = 1000;// event will fire every sec

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs) {
/// your logic to add new text, and change text position to give scroll effect
}
```

In TimerEventProcessor, put you logic to change text position that is to change it y coordinate, add new text in the bottom, this way you can create the scroll effect

In the timer.tick event handler you could do

```
if(label.Location.Y < 20)
label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, this.ClientSize.Height);
else
label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y - 1);
```

Hope this help

Comment: im sorry for the dumb question, but is it possible for u to give example for the logic? example, i want to the text hello world! to scroll from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a Label control with text, and simply decrease its Vertical position with 1 (in pixels) every 1/20th of a second or so.

Comment: How would you handle a long stream of continuous text, though? Have a single label which spans way above and below the visible area? Break it into lots of label controls? Try and chop text out of the control as it scrolls off?

Comment: Why not put the entire text on a single, text-wrapping Label control? It would by far be the easiest solution.